# Is it possible to make a detached camera recorder for Android?

Tags: android

I need to make a detached camera recorder. The functionality should basically be that in an application you're able to use the camera only using the methods startRecording() and stopRecording().

All the guides and tutorials on the camera are on how to implement it using Intents? Also there's a lot of talk about the Surface view but I don't want a preview. I just want it to say "Camera started recording" in a toast and then it records until you call the stopRecording() method.

Is this possible?

My current code gives an IllegalStateException from the "recorder.Start()" line in my code.

```
package superrecorder;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.util.Log;

public class CameraRecorder {

    private File recording;
    private MediaRecorder recorder;
    private static Camera mCamera;
    private boolean hasCamera;

    CameraRecorder() {
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    }

    public void startRecording(Activity act) {

        hasCamera = checkCameraHardware(act);

        if (!hasCamera) {
            Log.v("CameraRecorder", "No camera on this phone");
            return;
        }

        Log.v("CameraRecorder", "Initializing camera recorder");

        mCamera = Camera.open();
        mCamera.unlock();

        recording = new File(act.getFilesDir() + "/Recording/Video", "rec.mp4");

        recorder.setCamera(mCamera);
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
        recorder.setOutputFile(recording.toString());

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("CameraRecorder", e.toString());
        }

        recorder.start();
        Log.v("CameraRecorder", "Start recording");

    }

    public void stopRecording() {
        if (!hasCamera) {
            Log.v("CameraRecorder", "No camera on this phone");
            return;
        }
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release();
        mCamera.lock();
        mCamera.release();
        Log.v("CameraRecorder", "Recorded video: " + recording.toString());
    }

    private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("CameraRecorder", e.toString());
        }

        return c;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of problems with your code:

```
c = Camera.open(1);
```

This may or may not work depending on how many cameras the device has. Plus that it is not clear whether or you get the back or front facing camera in case that the device has more than one camera.

You don't set a preview display. This is a must.

You don't set the video size. There are many devices where this does not work.

Once you have fixed this you need to find out whether it is possible on the device you use to set the video recording parameters one by one or whether you have to use camcorder profiles. For example the newest generation of Samsung phones (Note 3 for example) seem to work only with profiles.